# Ways to see the connected sum of $h$ copies of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ minus a point

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'd like to calculate the singular homology of the connected sum of  $h$ copies of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ minus $n$ points, and to do this I would like to know if the connected sum of  $h$ copies of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ minus a point is homotopic to a nice space, like a bouquet of $S^1$.

Comment: Try to find a polygonal representation of connected sum of $\mathbb RP^2$.

Comment: I got it, thank you!